# How do I access get the base type in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

After trying to grasp how to traverse the prototype chain in the generated Javascript, I failed to implement the function `WriteInheritedName()` in the example below. The idea is to find the base type and write its name. Any ideas?

```
class Animal {
}

class Snake extends Animal {
}

function WriteClassName( cls ) {
   console.log( cls.name );
}

function WriteInheritedName( cls ) {
   console.log( "I wish I new how to write Animal" );
}

WriteClassName( Snake );
WriteInheritedName( Snake );
```

Comment: There isn't really a practical use of the way you want to achieve it. If you want access to the super class in a constructor or method, use `super`. You can find the "Simple Inheritance" example in the dropdown menu of the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/).

Comment: The question is how to implement a generic reflection mechanism given only the object (function) referenced by ```global.A```. I.e. how to implement the function ```WriteInheritedName```. The assumption was to use ```getPrototypeOf()```, ```__proto__```, or ```prototype``` properties to determine the inheritance chain of any arbitrary object at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it out myself.

```
 function WriteInheritedName(cls) {
    console.log( Object.getPrototypeOf(cls.prototype).constructor.name );
 }
```

Comment: Should simplify to `Object.getPrototypeOf(cls).name`.